# Ranking list in ascending order but keeping the index same

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have a list of numbers, that I want to rank in ascending order, but their index is important, I want to keep them unchanged.

for example:

```
index 0  1 2 3  4  5  6 7 8  9

a =  [22,2,4,53,43,32,3,5,1,101]
```

to:

```
index  8 1 6 2 7  0  5 4  3   9
a =   [1,2,3,4,5,22,32,43,53,101]
```

how to arrange them like that?

Thanks

Comment: `indexes, values = zip(*sorted(enumerate(a), key=itemgetter(1)))` Imports: [`itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, my answer is an addition to [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68588018/10824407)'s *(<s>which posted 2 minutes after I left [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68587943/10824407#comment121213577_68587943) comment</s>)*.

There's built-in [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function which yields tuple of index and value of each item in iterable, you may pass it's result directly into [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) with [`itemgetter(1)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) as `key` argument. It will return list of tuples *(index, value)* sorted by second element *(which is value)*.

To get two separate lists from list of pairs, you can unpack list into [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and assign result to two separate variables.

Code:

```py
from operator import itemgetter

a = [1,2,3,4,5,22,32,43,53,101]
indexes, values = zip(*sorted(enumerate(a), key=itemgetter(1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can recreate the list as a list of tuples that are `(index, value)`:

```py
>>> arr = list(enumerate(a))
>>> arr
[(0, 22),
 (1, 2),
 (2, 4),
 (3, 53),
 (4, 43),
 (5, 32),
 (6, 3),
 (7, 5),
 (8, 1),
 (9, 101)]
```

You can then sort this either by the original index or the value using `0` for index and `1` for value:

```py
>>> sorted(arr, key=lambda x: x[1])
[(8, 1),
 (1, 2),
 (6, 3),
 (2, 4),
 (7, 5),
 (0, 22),
 (5, 32),
 (4, 43),
 (3, 53),
 (9, 101)]
```

Or using `itemgetter`, as suggested by [@Olvin Roght](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10824407/olvin-roght)

```py
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> sorted(arr, key=itemgetter(1))
```

Answer (score 1):

By definition, the index of an element in a list is it's location in the list.
If you want to keep the original indexes as information, you can change the elements of the list to be tuples/lists of length 2, with first element as the value, and the index as the second element.

```py
a = [1,2,3,4,5,22,32,43,53,101]

# adding original index to each element
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i] = (a[i],i)

# sorting the list based on the first number in each element
def compare(x):
    return -x[0]
a.sort(key=compare)

print(a)
```

EDIT: as suggested by the comments and other answer, you can replace some of the code using built-in functions and more compact syntax:

- you can `enumerate` constructor to, well, enumerate the list and then make a list from the object using the `list` constructor
- you can replace the compare function with a compact lambda. like `lambda x : x[1]`
  while I would usually make these changes when I code, I tried to make the code as simple as I can to understand, in case you are not familiar with some of the functions described above.

Comment: You're reimplementing built-in `enumerate()` and `operator.itemgetter()` functions. Also, if you want to get elements sorted in reverse order there's `reversed` argument in `list.sort()` function.

Comment: This is a bad answer, as already mentioned you should be using the [built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html)

Comment: @Alex, it's not bad, just some parts could be replaced by built-in functions and/or improved.

Comment: sorry, just wanted to make the answer as simple to understand as I can

Comment: @OlvinRoght, the built-in functions are there to be used and because they make reasoning about what code is doing easier. By using a loop to overwrite the list and a custom comparison function this snippet has obscured what is happening.

Comment: @atanay, nothing to be sorry about, that's ok. There're some suggestions, which may help you to learn something new.